# Lead conversion insufficient privillige when link to different Account

Tags: lead-conversion, insufficient-privileges

The issue is happen when during Lead conversion when the user specify Account that not owned by them.If Create New Account , it will success.If choose Account that owned by user it will success.

I checked the Profile at General User Permissions : Convert Leads is checked.
I checked Standard Object Permission:Account has Read,Creat,Edit access.

How to enable Lead conversion if the user assign the Lead to the Account that not owned by them?

Comment: Hi Unidha, Is your account has private sharing model. If that is the case then account which is getting visible has only read access. You need edit access for the accounts where lead is getting associated. Please check if user has edit access on the error giving account or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Account Team and add the user (other than the owner) in the Account Team. This can be done either by manually or by using trigger. Use the Account Team for that Account.

For automation you can refer this link:
[How to automate account team](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23606/how-to-automate-account-team)

Comment: @unidha is that solution solves your purpose?

Comment: I also come accross Account Sharing Rules, now I wondering which approach is better Account Team or Sharing Rule.Where I can find in advantages/limitation on these two approach?

Comment: Santanu Boral ,when I can add this Account Team member, on Lead trigger after update ?

Comment: Yes, you can add there

Comment: The issue is The Insufficient Privillige error is fired first and stop any trigger procesing.